# Why does result become redundant if I try to use Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to retrieve all the `community_topics` that contains the `search keyword` within either `community_topics.title` or `community_topics.body` or `comments.body`

But this code below retrieve and shows bunch of doubled, tripled or more! records:(
I only want them as single record.  How can I?

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.joins(:community, :comment_threads).merge(Community.not_deleted).where('community_topics.title like ? OR community_topics.body like ? OR comments.body like ?', "%"+params[:search]+"%", "%"+params[:search]+"%", "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('last_active_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: You can use `uniq` method at the end of your query before pagination

Comment: @AmitThawait How can I add that to my code?

Comment: `@community_topics = CommunityTopic.joins(:community, :comment_threads).merge(Community.not_deleted).where('community_topics.title like ? OR community_topics.body like ? OR comments.body like ?', "%"+params[:search]+"%", "%"+params[:search]+"%", "%"+params[:search]+"%").order('last_active_at DESC').uniq.page(params[:page]).per(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something such as:

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.joins(:community, :comment_threads)
                    .merge(Community.not_deleted)
                    .where('community_topics.title like :term 
                            OR community_topics.body like :term 
                            OR comments.body like :term', 
                            term: "%#{params[:search]}%")
                    .order('last_active_at DESC')
                    .uniq.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

However, the query is overcomplicated. Why is `Community.not_deleted` being merged? Why are you passing in `page` and `per`? Is this being implemented in a controller? If so, extract into your model. Create relevant scopes and methods. Here is an example (untested):

#### model

```
model CommunityTopic

  scope :latest_active, order('last_active_at DESC')
  scope :eager, joins(:community, :comment_threads).merge(Community.not_deleted)

  def self.search(term)
    eager.where('community_topics.title like :term 
                 OR community_topics.body like :term 
                 OR comments.body like :term', 
                 term: "%#{term}%").uniq
  end

end
```

#### controller

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.latest_active.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

That's just a rough example. If you can explain why you're using `Community.not_deleted` merge, could probably clean that up. Could you add details with the actual sql query produced from the above?